# how to search text in json file that Google vision api created from pdf

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-vision

Is there any way to search text in json files that Google vision api created from pdf.
searching of text should be happen over Google cloud storage only

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage is an Object based storage solution that does not provide processing features. In order to perform any process job over the Cloud Storage data you would need a computing/processing solution, and I’d opt for a serverless option such as Cloud Functions.

I’ve found at the Cloud Functions Docs [a sample application](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr) that integrates several APIs with Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage, I think you can use it as a guideline to develop your own setup.

Once you have the mentioned setup you could apply a regex implementation to search for the desired data, how to implement it will depend on the runtime, libraries and technologies that you choose to use.